# What to do if after DoExpressCheckoutPayment payment status is other than Completed?

Tags: paypal, express-checkout

Suppose I'm finalizing the payment with `DoExpressCheckoutPayment` and receive a status other than `Completed` in `PAYMENTINFO_0_PAYMENTSTATUS` (for example - `Pending`). What am I supposed to do next from PayPals perspective - will I be notified to my `PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NOTIFYURL` when it resolves to `Completed` or should I give up right there and simply consider it failed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, when the status of a transaction changes you will receive an additional IPN with the same txn_id.

Comment: And same custom field?

Comment: Yes, you should get the same custom field, although I haven't tested that specifically.